# Facet, plot axis on all outsides

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to mirror the x-/y-axis to the opposite side (only outside, no axis on the inside)? My goal is to get something like:

[image]

---

**MWE**

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(rows = "Species")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `guides()` function to set axes for secondary positions as well, see example below. To have it more like your example, the strip placement should be changed to `"outside"`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(Species)) +
  guides(
    x.sec = "axis", y.sec = "axis"
  ) +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1))+
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1))+
  facet_grid(rows = "Species")
```

[image]

Comment: Also thank you, looks great too. Upvote. I'll check later which one I prefer :-)